# Predicted value in simple LSTM keeps accumulating

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

After each epoch y_pred simply keeps increasing
input at each batch is 64x10 tensor, trying to predict max of the vector at each row.
I thought the gradient might not be going to 0 between batches, but I that wasn't the case.
I tried changing LR, epoch, LSTM layers (LSTM to RNN), hidden size etc, nothing helped.

BTW, using simple sequential network of dense and relu instead of lstm worked perfectly

Following is the code:

```
LR = 0.0001 
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=1, hidden_layer_size=100, output_size=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_layer_size)

        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, output_size)

#         self.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1,max_array_len,self.hidden_layer_size),
#                             torch.zeros(1,max_array_len,self.hidden_layer_size))

    def forward(self, input_seq):
#         lstm_out,self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(input_seq.view(len(input_seq),max_array_len, 1),self.hidden_cell)
        lstm_out,self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(input_seq.view(len(input_seq),max_array_len, 1))
        predictions = self.linear(lstm_out[:, -1,:])
        return predictions
model=LSTM()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LR, weight_decay=0.8)   # optimize all cnn parameters
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()                       # the target label is not one-hotted
print(model)

EPOCHS=2000
for i in range(EPOCHS):
#     model.train()
    for step, (seq,labels) in enumerate(train_data):
        model.zero_grad()
        labels=labels.view(labels.shape[0],1)
        y_pred = model(seq)
        loss = loss_func(y_pred.float(), labels.float())
        
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()  
    if i%10 == 0:
#         print(y_pred.shape,labels.shape)
        print(y_pred)
        print(f'epoch: {i:3} train_loss: {loss.item():10.8f}')

print('Finished Training')
```

y_pred i am gettting is:

````
tensor([[0.2661],
        [0.7536],
        [1.4659],
        [2.4905],
        [3.8662],
        [5.4478],
        [6.8958],
        [7.9347],
        [8.5493],
        [8.8773],
        [9.0486],
        [9.1409],
        [9.1931],
        [9.2244],
        [9.2441],
        [9.2570],
        [9.2657],
        [9.2718],
        [9.2761],
        [9.2792],
        [9.2815],
        [9.2831],
        [9.2843],
        [9.2853],
        [9.2860],
        [9.2865],
        [9.2869],
        [9.2872],
        [9.2874],
        [9.2876],
        [9.2877],
        [9.2878]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)```
````

Comment: instead of model.zero_grad() can u try with optimzer.zero_grad()...Though they are same plz try it once

Comment: Why are you retaining your graph?

Comment: Are you aware of what you're doing on this line `predictions = self.linear(lstm_out[:, -1,:])`? I'm guessing what you want to do is get the last output in the series but what you are doing is **getting the output of the last sample in the batch**.

Comment: This line `self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, output_size)` does not have `batch_first=True`.

Comment: Model.zero_grad and optimizer.zero_grad are the same here. I was doing retain graph since when using hidden in lstm input I was getting an error, with or without it I get the same result. Linear can't have batch_first argument

Comment: Lstm out dim is 64x5x100, lstm_out[:,-1,:] is 64x100, which is thought was required for linear which is 100x1 to give the output 64x1. 64 is batch size, 5 is input features, 100 is hidden features, 1 is output feature. Correct me if you think something is wrong

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions. While writing the reply I realized that since my input features is 5, the lstm input size should be 5 and seq shape should be 64x1x5 instead of 64x5x1 which I was doing earlier. It works now. Thanks everyone again.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this line, `self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_layer_size)`. Good to know you've resolved it.